# Not able to assign function, that takes derived class reference as parameter, to function pointer that takes base class reference as parameter

Tags: function, pointers, polymorphism, function-pointers, return-type

Hi I'm trying to create function pointer, that takes two references to base class and assigning it function, that takes two references to derived class.

Lets say I have created function pointer

```
typedef bool(*MOT_fptr)(const ColliderMesh::Mesh&, const ColliderMesh::Mesh&)
```

then I have function, that returns function pointer to selected function

```
MOT_fptr GetMOT(ColliderMesh::Type type)
{
    switch (type) 
    {
        case ColliderMesh::Type::Rectangle: 
            return &Collider::BoxOverlapTest; // error: return value type does not match the function type

        case ColliderMesh::Type::Circle:  
            return &Collider::CircleOverlapTest; // error: return value type does not match the function type

        default: 
            return UNDEF_PTR; 
    }
}
```

where functions `BoxOverlapTest` and `CircleOverlapTest` are declared as

```
static bool BoxOverlapTest(const ColliderMesh::Rectangle& rect1, const ColliderMesh::Rectangle& rect2);
static bool CircleOverlapTest(const ColliderMesh::Circle& circ1, const ColliderMesh::Circle& circ2);
```

Both class `ColliderMesh::Rectangle` and `ColliderMesh::Circle` are derived from base class `ColliderMesh::Mesh`. But I'm getting compile error, when returning `&Collider::BoxOverlapTest` and `&Collider::Circle` that says `return value type does not match the function type`.

So the question is.. is this even possible what I am trying to achieve and just missing something, or should I look for another solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. It didn't occur to me at that moment I can declare functions `BoxOverlapTest` and `CircleOverlapTest` parameters as reference to base `Mesh` class

So I declared those functions as

```
static bool BoxOverlapTest(const ColliderMesh::Mesh& rect1, const ColliderMesh::Mesh& rect2);
static bool CircleOverlapTest(const ColliderMesh::Mesh& circ1, const ColliderMesh::Mesh& circ2);
```

and then when I am calling my function and passing parameters to it, I just explicitly cast them to base class

```
auto MOTFunction = Collider::GetMOT(col1MT);
... my code ...
MOTFunction((ColliderMesh::Mesh)col1.m_Mesh[i], (ColliderMesh::Mesh)col2.m_Mesh[j]); // explicitly casting them
```